# Pandas Date Conversion: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current research project, I am planning to analyse rows between two dates within a JSON file on basis of Python/Pandas. When converting the JSON `Date` object into the Pandas format, I am receiving the following notifcation `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` with reference to the line `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`.

I have already checked some pages referring to the same problem but have not found a solution yet. Is there any smart tweak to get this running?

Below is a sample of the JSON file:

```
[
{"No":"121","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2017","Text Main":"Sample text"}
]
```

The relevant code segment looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

# Loading and reading dataset
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
df = json.load(file)

# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()

# Converting the Date format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Comment: you haven't created a dataframe, you have a dictionary, do `df = pd.json_normalize(file)` then do your datetime methods

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The amendment is leading to an error `KeyError: 'Date'` for the same line though.

Comment: `print(df.columns)` does Date exist?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your JSON?

Comment: Have added a sample of the JSON file to the initial question. The suggested print line converts into an empty dataframe but the `Date` entry exists in the original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = open("1.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df)

    No Stock Symbol       Date    Text Main
0  121            A 2017-05-11  Sample text
```